# How to resolve this ambiguity in generic extension methods?

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

```
private static void TestAmbiguousGenerics()
{
    var string1 = "Hello".Foo(s => s + " world"); // works
    int? n = 123;
    var string2 = n.Foo(x => (x + 1).ToString()); // compiler error
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}".Fmt(string1, string2));
}

public static string Foo<T>(this T obj, Func<T, string> func) where T : class
{
    return obj == null ? "" : func(obj);
}
public static string Foo<T>(this T? str, Func<T, string> func) where T : struct
{
    return str == null ? "" : func(str.Value);
}
```

The compiler can't tell whether I'm calling the first overload of `Foo<T>` where `T` is `Nullable<int>`, or the second overload where `T` is `int`.  Obviously I could make this work by explicitly calling `n.Foo<int>()`, but is there a way to make the first overload exclude `Nullable<>` from the restriction of what `T` can be?

Comment: If your code is representative of your actual usage, the first method (without the constraint) will actually perform everything you need it to.  The null check eliminates the null values and `Nullable<int>.ToString()` produces the same result as `int.ToString()` when the value is not null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No - both methods are applicable in terms of overload resolution; the type parameter constraints are only checked *after* the best overload is picked.

There's a [really evil way of working round this](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/11/02/evil-code-overload-resolution-workaround) but personally I'd *either* give the two methods different names *or* provide the type argument explicitly.

Comment: Wow.  Seriously evil.  We are not worthy.